# Information loss while writing array to a file

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have a problem. I wanted to use libcurl and libtidy to save an html file to xml on my pc.

This is code I found for getting the website (in my case for testing google.com) and then tidying it. I got it from multiple sources and put it together.

```
CURL *curl;
std::string readBuffer;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

const char* input = readBuffer.c_str();

TidyBuffer output = {0};
TidyBuffer errbuf = {0};
int rc = -1;
Bool ok;

TidyDoc tdoc = tidyCreate();
std::cout << "Tidying..." << std::endl;

ok = tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyXhtmlOut, yes);
if (ok)
    rc = tidySetErrorBuffer(tdoc, &errbuf);
if (rc >= 0)
    rc = tidyParseString(tdoc, input);
if ( rc >= 0 )
    rc = tidyCleanAndRepair( tdoc );               
if ( rc >= 0 )
    rc = tidyRunDiagnostics( tdoc );               
if ( rc > 1 )                                    
    rc = ( tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyForceOutput, yes) ? rc : -1 );
if ( rc >= 0 )
    rc = tidySaveBuffer( tdoc, &output );          

if ( rc >= 0 )
{
    if ( rc > 0 )
    printf( "\nAnd here is the result:\n\n%s", output.bp );
}
else
    printf( "A severe error (%d) occurred.\n", rc );
```

The result is saved in `output.bp` as a `byte *`. Now I tried writing this to a .txt file, just for testing purposes (later to an xml file). For this I use these lines of code:

```
std::ofstream file;
file.open("C:/Testing/1.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
assert(file.is_open());

auto * charArray = (char*) output.bp;

file.write(charArray, sizeof(charArray));

file.close();
```

A file get created on the specified position but only a few characters get saved:

```
<html it
```

The rest of the document is just empty, no more lines or anything, thats all that gets saved. I really have no idea why this is happening as when printing out `output.bp` everything works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
file.write(charArray, sizeof(charArray));
```

`sizeof(charArray)` is always 8 (on a 64 bit architecture), since `charArray` is a `char*`. This is why you wrote 8 characters to the file.

To get the length of a null-terminated character string, you should be using `std::strlen()`. However, since you are using `TidyBuffer`, you can use `bp.size` instead, avoiding the O(N) operation.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot that. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: `TidyBuffer` has a size member. I would use that over strlen, especially when saving binary data.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you, I'm not familiar with `TidyBuffer`, I was just working off the info at hand. I'll ammend the answer.